# How to save data from html5 input type date/time as Date Time in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, datetime, html-helper

How to handle this two inputs so that both can be sent to the controller and save as Date Time? Or is any helpper/gem looks like date and time picker from html5?

## html5 inputs:

```
%input{:type => "date", :value => "yyyy-mm-dd"}
%input{:type => "time", :value => "07:00"}
```

## standard helper:

```
= f.datetime_select :time
```

**EDIT:**
Occurred to me simpler solution I checked and it works with datetime field:

```
%input{:name => "model[start_at]", :type => "date", :value => "yyyy-mm-dd"}
%input{:name => "model[start_at]", :type => "time", :value => "07:00"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your datetime field is called "started_at", try this:

1) in your model, define these two methods:

```
def started_at_string
  # return started_at datetime converted to a string in a desired format, e.g.:
  self.started_at.strftime(Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default])
end

started_at_string=(datetime_string)
  self.started_at = Time.zone.parse(datetime_string)
  # also you should process cases when the string is not a datetime
end
```

2) in your view:

```
f.text_field :started_at_string
```

3) apply this date picker to the text field:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ , and this time picker on top: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ , and you will get a nice datetime picker.

This method does not work quite nicely for iPhone, though (a screen keyboard and a picker pop up simultaneously and make it difficult to enter a date).